# XHTML - disable automatic browser spellcheck on textareas

Tags: xhtml, textarea, spell-checking

I have a textarea with random base64 code in it. The text inside it has a annoying thin red line underlining it in Opera.

Is there a opera html attribute that can disable the spell checker on that field?

`spellcheck="false"` seems to work in Chrome, but not in Opera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried making the textarea readonly by adding

```
readonly="readonly"
```

?
Or does the BASE64 code need to be editable?

Comment: well kind of. it should be able to be replaced, not edited like a normal text. but that requires ctrl+a + del and ctrl+v :)